# Highlights and active/redirect to bootstrap tab if error raised by jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I have a form with multiple tabs using bootstrap tabs.

Html Tabs structure like:-

```
<div class="tabs-container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1"> Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">  Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                    <!--Form field Here-->
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane ">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                    <!--Form field Here-->
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
                            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using **jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.13.0** to validate the form.

jquery Code like:-

```
<script >
$("#frmID").validate({
rules: {
name: {
required: true,
minlength: 3
},
}
});
</script >
```

I want to highlight the specific tab which contain that field(invalid data field) if the error occurred by jquery plugin and active that tab also.

I will highly appreciate if i can get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Providing a fiddle and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is also useful.

Comment: @secelite I have tried with the "highlight: function". but didn't get the solution.

Comment: I also tried to create a fiddle but tabbing is not working there. Hence, I haven't created that.

Comment: You should provide the code of what you have tried so far. The `highlight` function is what you need.

Comment: @secelite yes i have tried with the same highlight code and its working for me now I will share the correct code in answer please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use the **Jquery validate highlight** and its work for me.

```
<script>
$("#frmID").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
        },
    },
    highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
        $(element)
        .closest('.form-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
        if($('#tab-1').find('div.error').length != 0){                                                
        $('#tab-1_a').css('color', 'red');
        }else{
         $('#tab-1_a').css('color', '#A7B1C2');
        }
        if($('#tab-2').find('div.error').length != 0){
        $('#tab-2_a').css('color', 'red');
        }else{
         $('#tab-2_a').css('color', '#A7B1C2');
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
        $(element)
        .closest('.form-group').removeClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
    }

});
</script>
```